# Running PowerShell script from a batch file successful on 32 bit but fails on 64 bit

Tags: powershell, batch-file, 64-bit

I have a powershell script (test.ps1) and I want to run this from a batch file. The batch file contains the following:

```
PowerShell –Command “& ‘.\test.ps1’” 001
pause
```

When I run the batch file (as administrator) on a 32 bit Windows 7 machine, the powershell script runs successfully. When I try and run it on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>PowerShell –Command “& ‘.\test.ps1’” 001
The term ‘.\test.ps1’ is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  ‘.\test.ps1’ 001
    + CategoryInfo              : ObjectNotFound: (.\test.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your script from `C:\Windows\system32` and there's no such script (usually this happens when the bat is started with admin privileges  ).
Change the directory or call it with a full path.

The easiest way to fix this - set `cd /d %~dp0` at the start of the batch script to change the directory on the location where the script is

Comment: The test.ps1 and the batch file are in the same folder (for example C:\test\).

Comment: Just checked both machines and when running the file, the 32bit machine says C:\test>... but the 64bit on starts C:\Windows\System32>.

Comment: So how do I tell the 64 bit machine to run from the folder I'm trying to run it from?  (I can't put the full path in because it could be anything, the people running it can copy the files to wherever they want)

Comment: Probably you started the script with `administrator` priviliges - in these cases it starts from system32

Comment: set `cd /d %~dp0` at the start of the batch  script to change the directory on the location where the script is.